# trigering application after row inserting

Tags: c#, sql

Hello i am looking for a technology which can help firing event after someone put the row into sql and this even will be transfer to some c# listner application, or this event will fire some c# application. Is this possible? I am using sql 2008 web server

Comment: Probably you doing something wrong...

Comment: How is that a remotely helpful comment? We all appreciate some humorous comments, but really, that's a waste of bytes. </irony>

Comment: Poor bytes, wasted for nothing :(

Answer (score 1):

You can create a SQL Server trigger on the Table, and in the trigger you can invoke a CLR Stored Procedure.

Comment: and how can i execute any exe file from stored procedure?

Comment: You can use xp_cmdshell for this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the DB your using to how Exactly to implement. But you need to look into triggers. These are chunks of code that reside on the database that can be told
To do something on certain database actions like on insert, on delete etc